# connecting to data base sends only one word iOS

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, database, xcode

I want to send some string text data from my iphone to the server.
I am using a php file on my server. The php works fine if i use it on
the webpage but only sends one word if there are 2 words nothing will 
be send like the connection does not exist.

PHP:

```
if (isset ($_GET["vic"]))
        $name = $_GET["vic"];
    else
        $name = "empty text";


$con = mysql_connect('sqlserver', 'username', 'pasword'); 
if (!$con) { 
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 
echo 'Connected successfully'; 
mysql_select_db(db_name); 

$sql = "insert into Vici (VIC) values('$name');";
    $res = mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());

mysql_close($con);


?>
```

iOS:

```
- (IBAction)add
{

    NSString *vic = txtVic.text;

    NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"http://URL",vic];

    NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];

    NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


    NSString *povezava = @"Connected successfully ";
    if([povezava isEqualToString:strResult])
        izpis.text = @"added";

}
```

I did not use any real info because its private. Than you.

Comment: Your `url` looks awkward..You need to remove the string `"URL"` from your `strURL`. So after you converted your data to string, it will say `<<Connected successfully>>`. Exactly as you typed there?.

Comment: the URL is just a variable of my URL that is `http://webpage.com/Database/phpFile.php?vic=`  <<Connected successfully>> is returned from the php file if connection is done

Comment: then your `strURL` should be like this.. 
`NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://webpage.com/Database/phpFile.php?vic=%@",txtVic.text];`

Comment: sadly it does not work. i tried to make it like i want to request data from a webpage but it only works whit one word. do u know what is the code for empty space ? maybe this is the problem

Comment: If that is your problem, `empty space` should be replaced by `+` or `%20`. There is this method, which will help you as explained in this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3905353/1083859

Comment: thanks man :) this works like a charm. can u please wrote it as a answer so i can give u points ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should replace
`NSString *vic = txtVic.text;`
with
`NSString *vic = [txtVic.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`
as @DineshRaja commented.

Answer (score 0):

NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"http://URL",vic];

This string will give You

> http://URLvic

If I understand correctly Your link should looks like http://URL/?vic=%@

> NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/?vic=%@",@"http://URL",vic];

Comment: `NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"http://URL/?vic=%@",vic];` this does not work, however `NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://URL/?vic=%@",vic];` will work but the resolute is the same